# Jquery checkbox checked and unchecked events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

i have developed a code in html in which checkboxes are managed by jquery.

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"></label>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td><p id="taks2">Task 2</p></td>

    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>        
  </tr>
```

jquery script is this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#checkbox2').click(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){

                $('#taks2').replaceWith('<s>' + $('#task2').text() + '</s>');


            }
            else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

if checkbox is checked by the user then "Task 2" should be converted to <s>Task</s> (output after using del or strike tag) and if the checkbox is unchecked then it should be converted again to previous form like "Task 2".

Comment: I posted a different solution, only with `css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css class to add and remove when the checkbox is checked and unchecked:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#checkbox2').click(function(){
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('#taks2').addClass('strike');
      } else {
        $('#taks2').removeClass('strike');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.strike{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"></label>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td><p id="taks2">Task 2</p></td>

  <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>        
</tr>
```

You can also shorten your code using `toggleClass()` like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#checkbox2').click(function(){
      var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
      $('#taks2').toggleClass('strike', isChecked);
  });
});
```

```css
.strike{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"></label>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td><p id="taks2">Task 2</p></td>

  <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>        
</tr>
```

Comment: thank you. it worked. but it worked only for one check box, what if i want to call this function for 5 to 6 times in html code then what i ll have to do?

Comment: @Deepak you need to share your HTML for that. Possibly create a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this using just `CSS`, using a selector that change the style of next `label` of `:selected` `checkbox`:

```css
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" /><label>Task 1</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" /><label>Task 2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah i can do so but i want to do this through jquery then how is that possible?

Comment: it's very simple, like the idea of @Ankit, toggle the class like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/454334/   see if what are looking for